# How to subclass pandas.Timestamp?

Tags: python, pandas, subclassing

Why is the third object below a Timestamp object? I was expecting a Time object.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

class Time(pd.Timestamp):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return pd.Timestamp.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

print type(Time(datetime(2012, 5, 1)))
print type(Time('2012-05-01'))
print type(Time(2012, 5, 1))
```

Here are the results I see from python 2.7.11 and pandas 0.19.0:

```
<class '__main__.Time'>
<class '__main__.Time'>
<class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works, but in an elegant world `pandas.Timestamp.__new__` would do the class assignment for me:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

class Time(pd.Timestamp):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        time = pd.Timestamp.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        time.__class__ = cls
        return time

print type(Time(datetime(2012, 5, 1)))
print type(Time('2012-05-01'))
print type(Time(2012, 5, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't answer your question, but FYI I get

```
<class '__main__.Time'>
```

for all 3 on python 2.7.13 and pandas 0.18.1.

The behaviour you see was introduced in [0.19](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#other-enhancements).

[Here](https://github.com/nps/pandas/commit/36f8a83947fb777f3110b408d22b8ba9d64bf01f#diff-05de2950b2c86c9828531957e02d1b87R346) is the relevant code change.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior might be because pandas Timestamp class defines `__new__()` not `__init__()` to construct a new object. See [this code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/_libs/tslibs/timestamps.pyx#L720)